# How to send SMS programmatically from react native?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to send SMS **programmatically** from react native and the requirement is that it will not bring up any dialog -- just send the SMS behind the scenes.
I tried **react-native-communications** but it does bring up a dialog that the user sees. Any idea?